# Can I make Android Studio show errors immediately, like Eclipse used to do?

Tags: android, android-studio

There is one thing I really miss about Eclipse and it was that if I commented out a public field, for instance, the project immediately turned red and all the classes that use this field, also turn red, so I know what I broke.

In Android Studio, I comment out a public field and nothing changes, and if I want to find which are the affected classes I either have to try to remember where I used it, or run a rebuild, wait for a minute, until the error appears.

Can I make Android Studio do this kind of check in real time like Eclipse did?

Comment: AndroidStudio has no automatic build, unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in Android Studio as well. But only for the current visible class.

Make sure Power Save Mode is not enabled. You can uncheck it at 'File > Power Save Mode'

Comment: too bad. are they going to introduce it in android studio 2? Btw the closest thing I can think of it either doing Find References before deleting the field, or Refactor -> Delete and it will show you where it is being used before deleting it...

Comment: If you want to delete anything with a check that It is not being used anywhere, Use Alt + Delete. It's a feature called Safe Delete. It will search in all of the files and will prompt if any of the file is using it. Give it a try.

Comment: As Safe delete already exist. So, I don't think they will introduce it in later Android Studio versions.